# How to disable rainbow indent without extension in vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image: i disabled all extension but code is rainbow]

I disabled all extensions but my bracket is rainbow.
I used 'Deveoper: Reload with Extensions Disabled'

Has this function been incorporated as a basic function? Does anyone have any clue how to turn this off?
Do I have to remove something?

Thank you for listening to my whining.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The brackets coloring is [native](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_60#_high-performance-bracket-pair-colorization) and not an extension. Go to the settings and search for bracketPair to disable.

> "editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": false